# How does VS Code determine the return values of `require()`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I found that some kinds of type declarations in JavaScript can't be analyzed correctly in VS Code.

**Examples:**

For example, when I tried to `require` a package [`express-promise-router`](https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router) like:

```js
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
```

This package has an `index.d.ts` with the content below:

```js
declare module 'express-promise-router' {
  import { Router, RouterOptions } from 'express';

  function PromiseRouter(options?: RouterOptions): Router;

  export default PromiseRouter;
}
```

But VS Code thought this statement would return `any` type and broke the related type annotations.

By the way, ES6 `import`s like `import Router from 'express-promise-router'` or only changing the `export default PromiseRouter` to `export = PromiseRouter` can solve the problem.

Another example is my own package. A JavaScript lib named `database.js` has its declaration file named `database.d.ts`. The content is like:

```js
// database.d.ts
// ...
export type ActiveClientsConn = MySQLConn & ActiveClientsSpecMethods;
```

```js
// database.js
// ...
/**
 * @param {import('./database').ActiveClientsConfig} params
 */
function ActiveClientsConn(params={}) {
  /** @type {import('./database').ActiveClientsConn} */
  let inst = MySQLConn(params);
  // ...
  return inst;
}
// ...
```

VS Code can correctly handle the return value of `ActiveClientsConn()` in `database.js`. But when it comes to another script (like `database_test.js`) and I try to `require` it:

```js
const database = require('./database');
const conn = database.ActiveClientsConn(params);
```

VS Code still can't give the expected type hint for `conn` (`any` given, `database.ActiveClientsConn` expected).

**Other information:**

- VS Code version: 1.66.0
- Node.js: 16.13.0
- `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": <omitted>,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bencode-js": "^0.0.8",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-promise-router": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "promise-mysql": "^5.1.0",
    "redis": "^4.0.4",
    "yaml": "^1.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.21",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0"
  }
}
```

So is there anything wrong with the type-hinting system of VS Code or the code? Any reply is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 2
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: In your post, you use the term "VS Code" when you really should be referring to `tsc` or the [TypeScript Language Server](https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server).

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: @Dai The content has been uploaded.